# I can't use Vercel api in frontend

Tags: vercel

{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
{
"src": "./index.js",
"use": "@vercel/node"
}
],
"routes": [
{
"src": "/(.*)",
"dest": "./index.js",
"methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
"headers": {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
}
}
]
}

this is my vercel.json code. i used vercel api in frontend to fetch data from data base but it was given an error below

"Access to fetch at 'https://final-server-cavbtvsb5-arafat-rahmans-projects.vercel.app/appointmentOptions?date=Dec%2011,%202023' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

But i do not get any problem if i use local api. what should i do now and what is problem for this.

I need a solution for this error and want to know the reason for this error.